# What is prefered method to show Centered pop-up with dim background using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

Like this page http://webappsledger.com/

This is loading pop-up in iframe. Can we same type of effect to keep pop-up content hidden at same page?

Which approach is better? I need to keep a Web Form in pop-up. with **successfully submitted** message in same popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is generally called a 'Lightbox', and there are many many options out there.

One of my favorites is Colorbox ( http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/ ), and it supports iframes right of out the box.

Their demo pages have various usage, including using iframes:

http://colorpowered.com/colorbox/core/example1/index.html

Comment: Can we submit a form even staying at iFrame popup?

Comment: You can submit a form and the iFrame will stay open and active - if you need to close it you can look into doing something like    parent.$('.yourElement').colorbox.close();